# How to call methods user controllers in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel

I created controllers IndexController and FontCorrector. And I want use methods FontCorrector in IndexController. 
My FontCorrector code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FontCorrector extends Controller
{

    public function ConvertToDefault($text)  // Convert To Default
    {
        $search  = array("ғ","ӣ","ҷ","ҳ","қ","ӯ");
        $replace = array("г","и","ч","х","к","у");

        $result  = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);

        $search  = array("Ғ","Ӣ","Ҷ","Ҳ","Қ","Ӯ");
        $replace = array("Г","И","Ч","Х","К","У");

        $result  = str_replace($search, $replace, $result);

        $search  = array("ѓ","ї","љ","њ","ќ","ў");
        $replace = array("г","и","ч","х","к","у");

        $result  = str_replace($search, $replace, $result);

        $search  = array("Ѓ","Ї","Љ","Њ","Ќ","Ў");
        $replace = array("Г","И","Ч","Х","К","У");

        $result  = str_replace($search, $replace, $result);

        return $result;
    }

    public function ctd($text)
    {
        $text = $this->ConvertToDefault($text);

        return $text;
    }
?>
```

Here my IndexController and my method call is calling the FontCorrector controller method which did not succeed to call:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\FontCorrector as fc;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function exec(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->input('lang-input') !== null)
        {
            echo fc::ctd($request->input('lang-input'));
        }

        return view("index");
    }
}
?>
```

**ErrorException:** "Non-static method App\Http\Controllers\FontCorrector::ctd() should not be called statically"

Comment: dont call other controller's function from a controller, create a repository,trait, class or helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call like this

```
$fc = new FontCorrector;
echo $fc->ctd($request->input('lang-input');
```

but there is better way to do that you can make trait for that

Like in your `app/Traits/FontCorrector.php` create file then

in **FontCorrector.php**

```
public function ConvertToDefault($text)  // Convert To Default
{
    ...

    return $result;
}

public function ctd($text)
{
    $text = $this->ConvertToDefault($text);

    return $text;
}
```

and in **IndexController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Traits\FontCorrector;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    use FontCorrector;

    public function exec(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->input('lang-input') !== null)
        {
            echo $this->ctd($request->input('lang-input')); // call it 
        }

        return view("index");
    }
}
```

you use this package for traits: https://github.com/ajayexpert/artisan-trait-maker

Comment: +1 Here's the better way to do this. No need for my writing a second answer. Separating the FontCorrector is the best way to go because you may end up using it severally

Comment: even he can make it as helper function.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to solve this but I'll give you the simplest dirtiest method but this has more to do with Object Oriented Programming than Laravel specifically.

You need to instantiate FontCorrector in your code before calling the method. Because ctd() is not a static method.

You can do this by editing your **IndexController** like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\FontCorrector as fc;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function exec(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->input('lang-input') !== null)
        {
            $fc_obj = new fc;
            echo $fc_obj->ctd($request->input('lang-input'));
        }

        return view("index");
    }
}
?>
```

There's many things wrong with doing it like this but I understand you'd rather have something working before anything else.

Comment: And what is the best method of calling if this is the dirtiest method?

Comment: It's not recommended to have controllers call each other or for them to have a lot of code. A better way would be to create a custom helper. I'm not a php/laravel expert but I'll add a second answer showing how

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to call or instantiate a controller instance in another controller, because you can use custom [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers). 
But, if you really want to do it this way, then in your `IndexController`, you can use laravel dependency injection, I think this would be the better way of doing this.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\FontCorrector;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function exec(Request $request, FontCorrector $fc)
    {

        if($request->input('lang-input') !== null){
            echo $fc->ctd($request->input('lang-input'));
        }

        return view("index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialise "ConvertToDefault" and "ctd" functions as "public static function" because you are accessing it from another controller.

Try this way:

```
public static function ConvertToDefault($text)  // Convert To Default
{
    $search  = array("ғ","ӣ","ҷ","ҳ","қ","ӯ");
    $replace = array("г","и","ч","х","к","у");

    $result  = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);

    $search  = array("Ғ","Ӣ","Ҷ","Ҳ","Қ","Ӯ");
    $replace = array("Г","И","Ч","Х","К","У");

    $result  = str_replace($search, $replace, $result);

    $search  = array("ѓ","ї","љ","њ","ќ","ў");
    $replace = array("г","и","ч","х","к","у");

    $result  = str_replace($search, $replace, $result);

    $search  = array("Ѓ","Ї","Љ","Њ","Ќ","Ў");
    $replace = array("Г","И","Ч","Х","К","У");

    $result  = str_replace($search, $replace, $result);

    return $result;
}

public static function ctd($text)
{
    $text = TestController::ConvertToDefault($text);

    return $text;
}
```